# Mediawiki doesn't hold Session

Tags: php, session, mediawiki

I am using Mediawiki 1.23.6. Since a few days it is not longer possible to log in "normally". I always have to click the checkbox "keep me logged in". Otherwise the Wiki tells me I am not logged in when I try to edit an article. But when I go to the login it says "You are already logged in as ....". This does not happen when I click keep me logged in. Cookies are enabled in all browsers.

When I try now to upload a picture (tried different filetypes) it gives back a message like "Your edit couldn't be saved. Sessiondata were lost".

So it seems to have a problem to save sessions at all. I already set the *session_save_path* to a writeable folder and files are stored there.

Comment: You should put some code where you succeeding login and starting the session etc.

Comment: Hi bluebrain,
I don't make changes to the code and use Mediawiki as is. ;-)

Comment: then  you might put some configs or some access/error logs.

Comment: The only wa to post an error log is the link to one: http://ahlenwiki.de/errors/-debug_log.txt

Comment: Is this on a single PC, or do many users of your site have this problem? Maybe you try to explicitly clear all cookies in the browser and restart the browser. That may end any corrupted sessions.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [memcached issue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Memcached#Loss_of_session_data_when_saving). The log you posted confirms you have memcached enabled, but it's probably not working correctly (please delete that log file now, you shouldn't be sharing that private data!).

Your wiki is not huge, only some 1300 pages and 200k visits. Are you sure you really need memcached? I suggest that you disable it, configure APC (warning, replaced by OPcache in PHP 5.5) and go through the other [performance tuning](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Performance_tuning) steps first.

Then, if you still have a need for it, try to use memcached as well, but be more careful in its configuration.